# SwiftUI App resets SKScene after becoming active again

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, spriteview

Every time my app goes into the background and then becomes active again, SpriteView always resets and the SKScene goes back to the beginning of the level. How can I stop this or what am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
struct GameContainer: View {

    private var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = Splash()
        scene.size = Size.shared.setupSceneSize()
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        return scene
    }  

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene, options: .ignoresSiblingOrder)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}

struct Game: View {

    ...

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                GameContainer()
                ....
```

**Update**:

```
struct GameContainer: View {

    static var scene = Splash()

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: GameContainer.scene, options: .ignoresSiblingOrder)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}

class Splash: SKScene {
     override init() {
         super.init(size: Size.shared.setupSceneSize())
         scaleMode = .aspectFit
     }
     ....
}
```

Comment: I’m not too familiar with sprite kit but your scene is a computed property every time it is accessed it is computed/recreated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now. Did you find any solution to this in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size and scale mode of the scene *inside* `Splash()`, then make `scene` static. I think that should solve the problem of the SpriteView reloading all the time.

```
struct GameContainer: View {

    static var scene = Splash()

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: GameContainer.scene, options: .ignoresSiblingOrder)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}

struct Game: View {

    ...

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                GameContainer()
                ....
```

Comment: I tried it but it still yields the same result.

Comment: @JamesCastrejon I'm using this strategy in my own app, so I know it works. I had the same problem as you. I'd recommend taking a second look at your implementation of what I described. Also, you could try taking `GameContainer()` *outside* the `NavigationView`. Not sure if that would change anything, but I don't have a `NavigationView` in my own implementation, so maybe that's the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The Navigation View is there because of how I designed my game.

Comment: I tried it twice today and it still didn’t work without/outside the Navigation View.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Where is `Game` used? Is it in your `ContentView`? Can I see how you've implemented it?

Comment: Your answer didn't work for me, as in it didn't do what was expected. Its still has the same results. I don't have a ContentView. I replaced it with the Game view. I can't have GameContainer out side NavigationView because Navigation View will cover it or GameContainer will cover the whole UI. I'll update my question to show my implementation of your answer.